# How to make image appear on top of list item in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on my website, and I am trying to make an image appear on top of a list item.

Here is a jsfiddle to display my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/L6qvzjz4/

```
<li> TEXT <img src="link"> </li>
```

The immage appears beside the first list item, but I want it to appear directly on top of the text. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can do this very easily. Just use `position:relative;` on the list item, and `position:absolute;` on the image. Then position the image where you want using `top` and `left`:

```
li{
    position:relative;
}

img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L6qvzjz4/2/

Comment: when i am answering this...your ans is as mine. i  support u.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. If you want to have the img in a list:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><img src=""></li>
    <li>Text</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
    list-style: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L6qvzjz4/1/

But the **nicest** way is to use **figure** and **figcaption** tag. In this example, I have centered the text and the images:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50"/>
            <figcaption>
                Some description
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50"/>
            <figcaption>
                Some description
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50x50"/>
            <figcaption>
                Some description, some description, some more description
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/00xuxwb6/

Comment: Thank you so much! All of the answers helped a lot, and I will try out all of them. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put your image in a separate

as follows:

```
<ul><li><img src="https://www.google.ca/search?q=happy+face&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=579&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=TU7pVI-vHcG2yATetID4Dg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgdii=_&imgrc=Mv3LpH0uH8yauM%253A%3BVE7ZGYGvYa5sVM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fupload.wikimedia.org%252Fwikipedia%252Fcommons%252Fthumb%252F8%252F85%252FSmiley.svg%252F2000px-Smiley.svg.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fen.wikipedia.org%252Fwiki%252FSmiley%3B2000%3B2000"</li> 
<li> Picture1</li>
<li> Picture2</li>
<li> Picture3</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following CSS:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

li {
    position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lemoncurry/8fqz37fe/2/

Answer (score 0):

you could simply give the same width to your li and img. and put the text after your image.
for example your code could be

```css
ul{
    width: 300px;
}
ul li{
    width: 100%;
}
ul li img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul> 
    <li><img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png">
    Picture1 </li> 
    <li> Picture2</li>
    <li> Picture3</li>
</ul>
```